# How do I delete a doubly linked list in C?

Tags: c, struct, free, doubly-linked-list

I've created a doubly linked list, filled it with values and now I want to delete it and remove all the values to avoid memory leaks. Here's what I wrote as well as the structs that were used when creating the doubly linked list. Both those functions will be called towards the end of the main function.

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    char *value;
};

// The type for a list.
typedef struct list
{
    struct node head;
} List;

// The type for a list position.
typedef struct list_pos
{
    struct node *node;
} ListPos;

void list_destroy(List *lst)
{
  List p,q;
  p = *lst;
  while (p)
  {
      q = p.head->next;
      free(p);
      p = q;
  }
  *lst = NULL;
}
// Remove the value at the position and return the position of the next element.
ListPos list_remove(ListPos pos)
{

}
```

Comment: Initialize `p` to the first node: `struct node *p = lst->head;`

Comment: Don't describe parts of your code but show a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have the right general idea: you walk the list and free each node, making sure to grab any needed data from each node (in particular, the pointer to the next node) while the node holding it still exists.  Your case differs from some that you might have seen, however, because instead of handling the overall list via a bare pointer to the head node, you have a separate object, of a separate type (`List` / `struct list`), to represent the list itself.  This approach has much to recommend it, including, especially, the use of (apparently) a dummy head node, which provides for a variety of algorithmic simplifications.  This is usually how I write a linked list.

But because `struct list` is not `struct node`, you cannot set a list pointer equal to a node pointer.  Instead, create a `struct node *` to track your position. The first node to free would be the one referenced by `struct node *to_free = lst->head.next`, and the one after that would be the one referenced by `to_free->next`.

Note that you might need to free the `struct list`, too.